# Error 400 when submitting form but information is still received in google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I am receiving a error 400 when submitting a form, yet the data is transferred to my Google Sheet as intended.

I've read up on what may cause a 400 error but my understanding is not advanced enough to spot the error in the code.

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('jSignature')
      .evaluate();
}

function saveImage(bytes, sign){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FormResponse');
  var dateObj = Date.now();
  var bytes = bytes.split(",")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(bytes[1]), 'image/png');
  var fileName = blob.setName("Signature "+dateObj).getName();
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("myFolder"); //replace with your folder id
  var url = sigFolder.createFile(blob).getId();
  Logger.log(url)
  var carrier = sign.carrier;
  var address = sign.address;
  var dname = sign.dname;
  var dnum = sign.dnum;
  var date = sign.date;
  var time = sign.time;
  var tractortruck = sign.tractortruck;
  var odom = sign.odom;
  var imageCell = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues([[carrier, address, dname, dnum, date, time, tractortruck, odom, url]]);
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/willowsystems/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<center><h1><big><big>DRIVER VEHICLE INSPECTION REPORT</big></big></h1>
<h5>AS REQUIRED BY THE D.O.T. FEDERAL MOTOR CARRIER SAFETY REGULATIONS</h5></center><br>
<form id="customerForm" action="/action_page.php">
<div class="container">
  <label for="carrier">Carrier:</label>
    <select id="carrier" name="carrier" required>
      <option value="My Company">My Company</option>   
      </select><br>
    Location:
  <table id= "Address">
  <tr>
  <td>PDX</td>
  <td>EUG</td>
  <td>SEA</td>
  <td>SFO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="radio" id="PDX" oninput="this.className = '';EUG.className = '';SEA.className = '';SFO.className = ''" name="Address" value="PDX"></td>

  <td><input type="radio" id="EUG" oninput="this.className = '';PDX.className = '';SEA.className = '';SFO.className = ''" name="Address" value="EUG"></td>

  <td><input type="radio" id="SEA" oninput="this.className = '';EUG.className = '';PDX.className = '';SFO.className = ''" name="Address" value="SEA"></td>

  <td><input type="radio" id="SFO" oninput="this.className = '';EUG.className = '';SEA.className = '';PDX.className = ''" name="Address" value="SFO"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
      <label for="Driver name">Driver Performing Inspection:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dname" name="drivername" placeholder="Your full name" required><br>
  <label for="Driver Employee ID number">Driver's Employee Number:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="dnum" name="drivernumber" placeholder="Your employee number" required><br><br>
  <label for="Date">Date Performed:</label><br>
  <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required><br><br>
  <label for="Time">Time Performed:</label><br>
  <input type="time" id="time" name="time" value="now" required><br><br>
  <label for="Tractor/Truck#">Tractor / Truck #:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="tractor/truck" name="tractortrucknum" placeholder="Your vehicle number" required><br><br>
  <label for="Odometer">Odometer Reading:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="odom" name="odometer" placeholder="Vehicle odometer reading" required><br><br>
<b><big>Signature:</big></b>
<div id="signature"></div><br>
<img id="rendered" src="" style="display:none">
<input type="submit" value="Submit and close" onclick="renderSignature();saveImage();"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
<script>

  $("#signature").jSignature({
    'background-color': 'transparent',
    'decor-color': 'transparent',
  });

  function renderSignature(){
    $("img#rendered").attr("src",$('#signature').jSignature('getData','default'));
  }

    function saveImage(e){ //This sends the image src to saveImages function
    var bytes = document.getElementById('rendered').src;
    console.log(bytes);
    var sign = {
      carrier: document.getElementsByName('carrier')[0].value,
      address: $('input[name="Address"]:checked').val(),
      dname: document.getElementsByName('drivername')[0].value,
      dnum: document.getElementsByName('drivernumber')[0].value,
      date: document.getElementsByName('date')[0].value,
      time: document.getElementsByName('time')[0].value,
      tractortruck: document.getElementsByName('tractortrucknum')[0].value,
      odom: document.getElementsByName('odometer')[0].value,
    };
    alert("saveImage successful");
    google.script.run.saveImage(bytes, sign);
    return
  }

let date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
document.querySelector("#date").value = date;

$(function(){     
  var d = new Date(),        
      h = d.getHours(),
      m = d.getMinutes();
  if(h < 10) h = '0' + h; 
  if(m < 10) m = '0' + m; 
  $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr({'value': h + ':' + m});
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Ideally, I'd like to see the form take the user to a URL on submit.  I think I can figure this out once we resolve the 400 issue.  If anyone has advice, though, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This may not be relevant in the slightest, or just one part of a deeper issue but I seem to only get the error when /action_page.php is the action.  I'm not sure if it has to do with the particular method in which I collect the data, but this wasn't a problem in the initial days of creating this code.  I am going to go back and see if I can find exactly what changed.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak directly for Google sheets, but I suspect your code is okay.

Have a read of this: [Google Sheets: Commonly Returned Errors](https://help.formstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019521651-Google-Sheets-Commonly-Returned-Errors)

Namely this:

> **Error: Google returned with status code 400:**
>   A Google Sheet Error 400 typically indicates that the credentials used in the integration are invalid. Try removing and re-adding the integration, updating the credentials if they have been changed at all for the Google Sheets account being used. If able to re-add without getting an error, that should resolve any invalid access errors and you can re-run the integration on your existing submissions. This error can also be a problem with "Protected sheets and ranges" if you've altered your spreadsheet lately.
>   If Google Sheets returns a Bad Request - "Unable to retrieve cells" error, this is because you do not have column labels in the first row of your sheet. You have to create the sheet and fields on your sheet across the top row first before they will show in Formstack  - make sure the field names are the same as the field labels on your form.

I can only assume you submit the data and then immediately query it.

There's a very strong chance that the server has not processed / stored the data that you are currently trying to access.

> This error can also be a problem with "Protected sheets and ranges" if you've altered your spreadsheet lately.

The solution would be non-sophisticated and would involve one of two things:

1. `try / catch` block to attempt to query the site / data & if an error is returned, just process the page without any data
2. Wait 1 second then `try / catch` query. If error - wait 2 seconds then `try / catch` query. Repeat with increasing durations until 5 seconds and then just load the page without any data if no data is able to be retrieved after 5 queries.

However it would be good to double check that these are correct with relation to your spreadsheet / code combination (we do not have access to your spreadsheet):

- Your query is correctly formatted - particularly in reference to column names: [400 Bad Request : Invalid Query parameter value](https://support.workato.com/support/solutions/articles/1000229348-google-sheets-error-400-bad-request-invalid-query-parameter-value-for-sq-)
- The document you're trying to access is PUBLIC
- The query has correct ranges references: [Error: Unable to parse range](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/59bm63/trouble_with_google_sheets_api_quickstart_error/)
- A correct API key is being used (if applicable): [Google API Key for Google Sheets](https://www.vmix.com/help19/index.htm?GoogleAPIKey.html)

**Hopefully that helps, I've had similar issues with Sharepoint online queries before.**

Comment: I am looking into the try / catch, thank you for the advice!  I'll close this once I have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely**

- Either the sheet `'FormResponse'` does not exist in the spreadsheet to which the script is bound
- `DriveApp.getFolderById()` does not contain a valid folder Id
- Or you do not have the right to access this folder

Comment: Thank you for the advice but the information is transferred to the sheet FormResponse correctly and the image of the signature is saved in the folder correctly, yet the problem persists and honestly, everything works the way it should, the issue is almost entirely aesthetic.  I really wish this were the case, I could do with one less "work-around".

Answer (score 0):

This might seem dumb, but it doesn't seem as though I use /action_page.php to collect the data, it is all done in JS through the functions saveImage and renderSignature.  When looking at an old version of my code, I realized it didn't use /action_page.php.  So that must be something I picked up along the way from trying to improve my code, but it appears to be unnecessary.  When removed, all of my info is saved and transfers over to the google sheet exactly as I need it to and I don't get a 400 error on submit.

Thank you all for your help!  I hope this can help someone else.